# Revoke Google Login Credential in Favor of Something Else

Tags: discussion, login, user-accounts

For professional reasons, I am abandoning my google account, possibly deleting it, and switching to a SE id or other account. If possible, I would like to keep my reputation that I have built up over time.

The existing related questions seem to suggest one does not change the log in account but "add" a new one. I am not sure if that applies to my situation. I would appreciate it if someone could give some brief advise for this matter.

**Question:** Is there a way to keep my reputation while revoking my google account that I used to set up the log in the beginning or would I have to start from scratch?

Comment: It's all in the faq. Read after "This gets a bit more complicated when you're trying to add a Stack Exchange OpenID"

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard That is helpful, thank you. So in essence, there is no way to remove the former login credential, right? I suppose the main difference between the existing literature and my question here is I'm specifically asking about the feasibility to revoke an email from a SE account. That is to say, I learned from the other questions that I can *add* an account, but not so sure if permanently removing / revoking an account is possible or not.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard For example, even when I followed the steps to add my new credential, the recovery email I got from SE still had my google account listed as a possible login credential. I believe it said: "don't forget you can still use the following login credentials." I want to disable my google login credential.

Comment: @Arash does the "remove" link (as [shown here](/help/edit-credentials)) not work?

Comment: @Cai that worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, the remove link is available only when having more than one OpenID providers, so that you won't remove your only way to login.

Comment: @Sha I see the link even though I only have one login (I havn't tried clicking it mind, but it is there)

Comment: @Cai oh. Pretty sure it will give error.

Comment: @Sha probably. I'm not going to try though :)